# Kate is missing all button icons

Tags: xubuntu, icons, 15.10, kate

After removing KDE and switching to xfce, I discovered that Kate has lost all button icons, while Kile has not. I guess some configuration file refers to missing files, but what file is it. I tried to create a new, clean, user account, but the problem remains. In particular the search buttons has disappeared, since they have no text on them. [image: Save file dialog without any icons in toolbar]

## Update

A *fresh* install of Xubuntu on a second drive
gives the same error:

[image: Bad kate]

It is the same machine, booted from an external USB hard drive

The "Open" dialog box is not affected. Only toolbars and the "Save as" dialog are broken. I suspect a packaging bug.

Comment: you might need to install the kde icon theme.

Comment: @Raphael: The name of the corresponding package?

Comment: Have you tried simply reinstalling Kate ? The icons were probably part of KDE and a reinstall should download the missing icons for Kate too.

Comment: Maybe it's on purpose (in XFCE)?! I remember two options in **cinnamon** (in Theme-Settings) **SHOW ICONS IN MENUS** and **SHOW ICONS ON BUTTONS** which can be turned on/off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. Check here (answers #10 and #16):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/1509562

In short: installing package 'libqt5libqgtk2' before 16.04 and 'qt5-style-plugins' for 16.04 and later brings back MOST of the icons in KDE-Applications. For the few remaining ones, you have to fiddle around with the icon-settings in KDE-System-Settings.

HTH

Comment: in 18.04 this does not fix the problem any more

Comment: OK, need to install oxygen theme，then set to fallback to oxygen if icon not available.

Answer (score 3):

Placing .rcc file into `~/.local/share/kate` seems to bring the icons back (this also applies for krusader).

I did what is described in following webpages. 
However, kate is not using correct icon theme now.

https://dev.webonomic.nl/using-krusader-with-ubuntu-18-04

http://divideoverflow.com/2017/05/Configuring_Krusader_to_use_different_icons_template/

Comment: This worked for me: `apt install breeze-icon-theme-rcc` and `cp /usr/share/icons/breeze/breeze-icons.rcc ~/.local/share/kate/icontheme.rcc`

Answer (score 2):

You should install oxygen icon pack:

```
sudo apt-get install oxygen-icon-theme*
```

and if the left side panel (file list..) is missing:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge kate
sudo apt-get install kate
```

If kate holds configuration files in the home folder, then please delete those before re-installing. Let us know if this worked.

Comment: Even a complete fresh install did not work.

Comment: @user877329, then it's likely a bug. Sorry, can't help you there.

Comment: Do you think it is a package bug, or a bug in kate itself?

Answer (score 0):

Beside my comment, i found following:
(KDE apps running on XFCE have no icons in menus.)
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117414

Maybe you can try:

```
gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons true
gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons true
```