# What package(s) to install for missing button icons in KDE applications on Unity?

Tags: unity, icons, kde, icon-themes

I run some KDE applications on Ubuntu 16.04 Unity, such as KDE Connect.

I seem to be missing some packages that provide button icons:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know which packages to install to have these buttons being shown correctly?

Comment: `oxygen-icon-theme` I believe. Also check this: [Kate is missing all button icons](http://askubuntu.com/q/695409)

Comment: This package as well as `libqt5libqgtk2`is already installed on my system. I seem to be missing another package.

Comment: @orschiro, did you find what package was missing?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JonasCz [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785969/what-packages-to-install-for-missing-button-icons-in-kde-applications-on-unity/894213#comment1189915_785969), you need to install `oxygen-icon-theme`. But it's not enough to have installed, you also have to *use* it.
One way of doing this is to install Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Run it, go to Appearance / Icons and choose "Oxygen" instead of "Ubuntu-mono-dark" or whatever your current theme is. Then open the KDE Connect window again and it should have the icons.

### Further options

If you don't like the Oxygen theme you can try another one. KDE Connect is not tied to Oxygen. What you need is a theme with specific icon names. For example, the button from [your first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grgss.png) needs an icon named `edit-rename` (see the reference in [the source code](https://github.com/KDE/kdeconnect-kde/blob/f65392ca6bf726213d6054e4b16ca0a5c9e65a72/kcm/kcm.ui)):

```
<iconset theme="edit-rename">
```

You can search on your computer for icon themes containing such an icon:

```
find /usr/share/icons -name 'edit-rename*'
```

You could also search for available packages containing the icon:

```
apt-file find edit-rename.png
```

Or maybe you could even modify your current theme and create links with the desired names to the existing icons (I haven't tried this).

Answer (score 0):

[Instead of totally switching to a kde-theme](https://askubuntu.com/a/894213) it may be preferred to keep your preferred theme but set a fallback. In

~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini  or for all users

/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini  set the fallback-theme to an installed kde one:

```
[Settings]
gtk-fallback-icon-theme=breeze
```

The fallback theme can also be set using systemsettings5 in *Gnome application style* but I recommend against it as it also creates a ~/.gtkrc-2.0 which may corrupt your font settings.

[image: Screenshot systemsettings5]